# how to create auto slugfield in ddjango restframework in django like

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
 class AddCategory(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ['name', 'slug']  
   prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
```

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = Category
fields = ['name', 'slug', 'icon']
lookup_field = 'slug'

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Override your save method to generate your slug automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same thing. I have this on my models and want to move it to my serializers create method. I know your asking how to do it with DRF and I am not sure if its best to just keep it as is on the model itself just in case you have to manually update in the admin or similar.

```py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Software(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name='Software Name')
    slug            = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)
    status          = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Active')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Software')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Software')
        ordering = ["id", "name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def pre_save_software(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    slug = slugify(instance.name)
    instance.slug = slug

pre_save.connect(pre_save_software, sender=Software)
```